# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Timer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access

I'm making an app that involves changing UIImageViews by each second/step from a 4-step countdown timer. I get an Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when my program tries to execute the timer at "timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: true){(timer) in if i>4":

```
func startTimer(slider_Value: Float, coin: Int){
    let delay = Double(slider_Value/5)
    var i = 1
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: true){(timer) in
        if i>4{
            timer.invalidate()
        }else{
            switch(i){
            case 1:
                self.updateImages(UIImage(named: "P1Timer1"), UIImage(named: "P2Timer1"))
            case 2:
                self.updateImages(UIImage(named: "P1Timer2"), UIImage(named: "P2Timer2"))
            case 3:
                self.updateImages(UIImage(named: "Timer3"), UIImage(named: "Timer3"))
            case 4:
                self.logo.image = UIImage(named: "Timer4_Logo")
            default:
                self.updateImages(UIImage(named: "Timer0"), UIImage(named: "Timer0"))
                self.logo.image = UIImage(named: "SwipeIsh_Logo")
            }

            i = i+1
        }
    }
```

Anybody have any idea why this occurs? It just seems weird, and it's occuring in thread 1 (which is the main thread I assume, currently taking Hardware systems right now so I am not an expert on memory)

[Here is a screenshot of the crash/debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a7S7.jpg)

Comment: It runs fine in playgrounds. Show the debugger output.

Comment: I've updated my post above with the screenshot of the debugger @cora

Comment: Hope you are updating images on main thread

Comment: How do I check if my images are updating on the main thread? (Thread 1 I assume?) @Abhishek

Answer (score 2):

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: true){(timer) in
```

I am guessing that you call **startTimer()** more than one time. The problem is that every time you call this function you are replacing a timer object that is running with a new one without first invalidating it. You need to add `timer.invalidate()` just before you create a new one.

```
if i>4 {
     timer.invalidate()
}
```

this check will never be true. Every time you call this function, **i** is reset to 1.

Comment: I removed the edge case check. However, I added a 'timer?.invalidate()' before 'timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: true){(timer) in' and the problem still occurs. The timer is started based on a button press. The crash happens when I press the button once on app simulation startup, so I don't think two objects of startTimer() are occurring at the same time. Is the issue happening because of it possibly not happening on the main thread? And how do I check that, and ensure it's happening on the main thread? @cora

Comment: Thread 1 is the main thread. You can see, in the screenshot, that startTimer function is being called many, many times. Please post a new screenshot with modified code

Comment: Hey @cora Sorry I've been busy with finals but if you still are available to help out soon I'll post something in the next week. Thanks